# How to use special characters in Autohotkey script

Tags: autohotkey

I need help on setting up the password with `%#@!!`.

I tried few things referring to the earlier posts here but the script gives me an error:

> Error: This line does not contain a recognized action.

I am using Autohotkey version `1.1.34.03`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the Send command or Hotstrings are used in their default
> (non-raw) mode, characters such as **{}^!+#** have special meaning. To
> use them literally in these cases, enclose them in braces.
>
> Other characters such as **%;`** must be escaped.

For example:

```
Send `%{^}{!}{{}
```

or use the [raw mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#Raw)

```
Send {Raw}`%!{
```

or the [Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#Text) (**recommended**):

```
Send {Text}`%!{
```

See [Escape Sequences](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/EscapeChar.htm).